# Stackoverflow with Hibernate using sql IN (id, id, id, id..id)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, stack-overflow

I am getting the error below saying there was a stack overflow.  This is happening because a SQL statement with `IN (id, id, id...id)` has a ton of parameters.  Is there anyway to fix this?  This is happening in my local environment with Eclipse.

**JPA**

```
@Query(value="SELECT p FROM PendingCourseRegistration p WHERE p.sisId IN ?1 AND p.testId = ?2")
List<PendingCourseRegistration> findPendingCourseRegistrationInSisIdsAndTestId(List<String> sisIds, Long testID);
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.Abstract witingBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:416) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:237) ~[na:1.7.0_17]
    at antlr.BaseAST.toStringList(BaseAST.java:341) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]
    at antlr.BaseAST.toStringList(BaseAST.java:347) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]
    at antlr.BaseAST.toStringList(BaseAST.java:347) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]
    at antlr.BaseAST.toStringList(BaseAST.java:347) ~[antlr-2.7.7.jar:na]
```

**Hibernate Query**

```
2:26.763 [ocPifScheduler-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation
09:52:26.788 [Scheduler-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: SELECT p FROM com.test.PendingCourseRegistration p WHERE p.sisId IN (:x10_, :x11_, :x12_, :x13_, :x14_, :x15_, :x16_, :x17_, :x18_, :x19_, :x110_, :x111_, :x112_, :x113_, :x114_, :x115_, :x116_, :x117_, :x118_, :x119_, ...:xN) AND p.id = ?2
09:52:26.891 [Scheduler-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] Node: 'FROM'
    |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
    |  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'model'
    |  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'PendingCourseRegistration'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'p'
    |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'SELECT'
    |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'p'
    \-[WHERE] Node: 'WHERE'
       \-[AND] Node: 'AND'
          +-[IN] Node: 'in'
          |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'p'
          |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'sisId'
          |  \-[IN_LIST] Node: 'inList'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x10_'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x11_'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x12_'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x13_'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x14_'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x15_'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x16_'
          |     +-[COLON] Node: ':'
          |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'x17_'
```

Comment: Which version of hibernate do you have?

Comment: 4.1.12.Final is the version we are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our Grails project (2.3.6) with Hibernate 4.3.1.Final, we never had that error but we encountered another error due to **query buffer size** restriction:

Since you are using `in (?, ..., ?)` you write as much `?,` as you have items in your list, which means that for big list (says 50000) you may write a query of 100000 characters, and you may have this exception (here with pgSQL drivers):

```
Foobar.executeQuery("select f from Foobar f where f.id in (:ids)", 
                 [ids: 1L..100000L]); // Groovy way of creating a list of 100000 items.
```

And the error:

```
SqlExceptionHelper:146 - An I/O error occured while sending to the backend. 
SqlExceptionHelper:146 - This connection has been closed.
```

That why I think you might need to

1. Either split your id list into smaller list (like 500 items or so) and coalesced the result by hand, which is more work to do than the default spring-data you are using.
2. Either store the id list into a temporary table (which could prove to be a painful task using JPA). The temporary table would be a tuple of (key, sids). You would generate a temporary key (for the session), batch insert the ids into that table with the key, flush so that hibernate push the change onto the database, use that table using a subquery (`p.sidIds in (select sisIds from IdTable where key = ?1)`), delete data from that table. 
   While being a painful task, it may produce a boost in performance.

Comment: I basically just did multiple calls for each entity.  It's not a high traffic site so it wasnt a big deal.  Probably chunking it up or going to a different version could of worked but I didnt have time to do that.

Comment: Well, if you have guava, you could probably do something nice and have facilities to split your list and call your method. As updating Hibernate, I can understand while no to do it : the last is 4.3.6.Final. You would probably need to recheck your application on the whole before releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate this using Hibernate 4.2.4 
Can you please provide the version of Hibernate that you are using?
The other thing that I recommend is to try to put a break point on "antlr.BaseAST.toStringList()" when executing your method and see the runtime variables and the method that calls antlr's method and causes the loop

Hope that helps

Comment: Happens with Hibernate 4.3.6 with JDK 8 with 5000 entries in the list. I am using a CriteriaQuery: CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
                CriteriaQuery<E> cq = builder.createQuery(getEntityClass());
                Root<E> root = cq.from(getEntityClass());
                cq.select(root).where(root.get(getIdProperty()).in(ids));
                TypedQuery<E> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
                return query.getResultList();